# Login to StackOverflow without using your StackExchange login

Tags: support, stack-overflow, merge-accounts, login

I have a problem. Some time ago I created a stackoverflow account and while I was browsing the other sites of the "stack" family, I decided to create a StackExchange account which I used to log into those other sites, although I used stackoverflow for the most part and had my browser remember my login info for it.

But this morning for some reason I wasn't logged in into my stackoverflow account, so I clicked "login" and I was asked if I wanted to use my StackExchange id to login, so I chose yes... But this created a new stackoverflow user for me instead of logging me into my original account!!

So, apparently I now have two stackoverflow accounts:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1869062/sergeidave (my original account)

https://stackoverflow.com/users/2087645/sergeidave (the newly created one)

I've tried logging out and logging back in to stackoverflow but I'm always asked to use my StackExchange info!! How can I log into my original stackoverflow account!?

Or even better, **can I just merge** the two of them so that all is good!?

Answer (score 2):

Done.

The new account has been merged to your original.

Comment: \o/ for lightning service. :-)